# Different images for different resolutions in HTML resources in Android

Tags: html, android, image, android-webview, resolution-independence

How do you display different images for different screen resolutions (hdpi, ldpi, mdpi) in an embedded HTML resource of an Android app?

The HTML resource is located in `assets`, but can be changed if necessary.

If this is not possible, how do you change the display size of the image based on the screen resolution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do this with `@media` queries and `-webkit-device-pixel-ratio`. While the images have to be located in assets, you can use folders to organize them properly.

```
@media screen and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio:0.75) {
    #header {
        background-image: url('ldpi/background.png');
        width: 75px;
        height: 75px;
    }
}

@media screen and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio:1.0) {
    #header {
        background-image: url('mdpi/background.png');
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
    }
}

@media screen and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio:1.5) {
    #header {
        background-image: url('hdpi/background.png');
        width: 150px;
        height: 150px;
    }
}
```

According to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) (*Building web pages to support different screen densities*), this only works in Android 2.0 or higher.

You never know enough CSS, it seems.

Answer (score 1):

```
/*
MDPI Resources for Midium-density (Mdpi) screens (~160dpi).
CSS for medium density (Mdpi) Android layouts in here
webkit-device-pixel-ratio:1
*/
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1),
       only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1),
       only screen and (min-resolution: 160dpi)
{
    .title
    {
      text-align: center; 
      vertical-align: middle; 
      color: White; 
      font-size: 1.25em; 
    }
}


/* 
High Density Resources for (Hdpi) screens (~240dpi).
CSS for High density (Hdpi) Android layouts in here
webkit-device-pixel-ratio:1.5
*/
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
       only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
       only screen and (min-resolution: 240dpi)
{
    .title
    {
      text-align: center; 
      vertical-align: middle; 
      color: White; 
      font-size: 2.25em; 
    }
}
```